# Excel VBA- Copy and paste text on left after CHAR(10)

Tags: excel, vba

If the following conditions:

A1=
fsfsdfsdfs

qewqeqewqe

B1=
RIGHT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1&" "))

Then B1 would display "qewqeqewqe".

This works only directly into an excel cell. How would I write this line of code given the following conditions above?

Something like the below?

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1,2).value= left(find(CHR(10), Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(1,1),&""))?????
```

I would not be asking if I had not searched for it. All I keep finding is how to do it in an excel file and not the VBA. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub test()

Dim txt As String
Dim fullname As String

txt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
fullname = Split(txt, Chr(10))

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = fullname

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Orig As Variant
    Dim txt As String

    Set rng = Range("A1")

    txt = rng.Value

    Orig = Split(txt, Chr(10))

    For i = 0 To UBound(Orig)
        Cells(1, i + 1) = Orig(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Check this out,
http://www.xlorate.com/vba-examples.html#Split%20Cells

Comment: Hello Davesexcel,

I am trying to understanding this by step. The loop is confusing me. Here is what I have now:

Sub test()

Dim txt As String
Dim fullname As String

txt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
fullname = Split(txt, Chr(10))

Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = fullname

End Sub

I get stuck on the last line when I debug.

Comment: I'll give you the credit for the right answer sir as it does help me do what I'd like it to do. I will re-post the second part of my code. I am not able to make it run still. Thank you Davesexcel, you have made my life easier.