# excel vba - simple split with no loop

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning Excel-VBA and I am trying to learn how to do things that will help me in the future. I have been trying to learn how to do a simple split without a loop. Although I got a code that I could use, I could not understand it.
[Excel VBA- Copy and paste text on left after CHAR(10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30336434/excel-vba-copy-and-paste-text-on-left-after-char10/30336670#30336670)

I have this mock from what I learned in the code I was pointed towards. I feel like I am close but no matter what I do I can not make the syntax work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I attached the code and a snippet of what I would like to see before and after. My code does not work in this line.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = fullname
```

The code is below

```
   Sub test()

    Dim txt As String
    Dim fullname As String

    txt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value
    fullname = Split(txt, Chr(10))

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = fullname

    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It fails because **fullname** is an *Array*.  To get the first element:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2).Value = fullname(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Gary's Student says - **fullname** will be an array.  The first problem you'll have is a type mismatch as you've declared **fullname** as a string.

You can paste an array into a range of cells or reference elements of the array as Gary said in his answer.

```
Sub test()

    Dim txt As String
    Dim fullname As Variant

    txt = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value

    'This will be an array containing 4 different values
    'based on your A1 cell containing 3 line breaks.
    fullname = Split(txt, Chr(10))

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        'The array must be pasted into 4 cells.
        '.Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, UBound(fullname) + 2)) = fullname

        'the above line is the same as:
        .Range("B1:E1") = fullname

    End With

End Sub
```